# Some Questions on Spring

Tags: spring

Please respond to below questions.

1) where are the beans loaded. will they be loaded in Spring ApplicationContext?
      OR they are loaded in the heap by ApplicationContext.
2) In a spring Web Application, If the Application is not being used for a day or so, will the ApplicationContext Object garbage collected?

3) How to make singletons thread safe?
4) what are the other Objects that have Threadsafe issues in Spring.
5) BeanPostProcessor's methods execute for each and every bean in the application.
How is it handled in case of thousands of object in a complex application.
Are the beanpostProcessors thread safe?

Comment: Split and refine questions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should better split these questions - each of them deserves a dedicated thread imho.

1. In any case, Spring loads the beans for you. How? It reads the metadata about the beans (xml/annotations based), and wires up them together. So spring does a "new" for you, But how to access this bean? Here ApplicationContext comes to play. Its just like a container for all these beans, a a container that allows to access the bean instance by its name (getBean("beanName") ).
   In a very simplistic approach you can think of the application context as a map of beans by name.
   I didn't totally understand the "Heap" concern here. Spring beans are just Java objects living in the JVM, so yes, basically they're loaded in the heap. The only difference is that they're loaded by spring and not by your code.
2. The application context won't be garbage collected because its stored across (and accessible from) the whole web application. 
   Of course the beans created by this application context can be garbage collected if they're not singletons or something. I know its a vague answer, feel free to refine your question.
3. Singleton in its core architecture has nothing to do with a thread safety. Yes, spring provides a 'singleton' bean scope. This means that each time you'll do a getBean call you'll get the same instance, so its a singleton (as long as you manage this bean only in spring). This definition doesn't influence on the design of the bean, so if you, say, create an instance of this class by just calling it's constructor (new keyword), you'll get an entirely different object of this type than that managed by spring.
   Its important to understand where the responsibility of Spring as a framework starts and when it ends :)
   So if you want your singleton to be thread safe, you should design it to be thread safe.
   The best would be doing it stateless, but again, it has nothing to do with spring, so please ask it in a different thread, or just google for "thread-safe design"
4. Don't really understood the question, so I can't answer, sorry :(
5. Again the thread safety of the bean post processor depends on what actually written there, its your code there, not the infrastructure code.

Hope this helps